# Sorting n elements in worst case of $\sqrt{n}\log n$

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Can $n$ elements be sorted in a worst case time of $\sqrt{n}\log n$? Why or why not?
I've seen algorithms being sorted in the worst case of $n\log n$, so why can they be or cannot be sorted in $\sqrt{n}\log n$?

Comment: Depend on the data. See counting sort

Comment: Without any assumptions on the data, any comparison based sorting algorithm takes $\Omega(n \log n)$. See [here](https://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall09/Lectures/6-moresorting/sortLB.pdf)

Comment: Have you consulted a textbook, or _any_ reputable resource about it? What makes you think about $\sqrt(n)$, specifically?

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible. You cannot sort $n$ elements without examining each element at least once, which takes at least $n$ operations.

$n=\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{n}\ge\sqrt{n}\cdot\log{n}$ for all $n>1$, assuming the logarithmic base is at least 2. (Of course, if you assume something completely asinine like $\log_{1.000001}n$, it would be technically possible for some values of $n$.)